# Pegar valores em array de um $post

Tags: php

Possuo um form onde estou pegando a escolha do usuário, e inserindo no array mas não acumula e só mostra a escolha atual. Como faço para acumular e a cada new post seja adicionado ao array?

```html
<?php 

include "filmelistar.php";
$escolhas = array();
$filme2 = $_POST["filme2"];

$movie = $tmdb->getMovie($filme2);
// returns a Movie Object

$escolhas[] = $movie->getTitle();

echo '  <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <br>
                Adicionado a lista!
                <ul>';
echo $movie->getTitle();

echo '          </ul>
            </div>
        </div>';

        echo "<p>Lista para assistir:</p>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($escolhas); $i++) {
          echo $escolhas[$i];
          echo "<br>";
        }




?>
```

Comment: O que tem na variável `$tmdb`? E qual é o seu objetivo com isso? Estudo?

Comment: Ela é a chamada de uma classe que também é um API do site TheMovieDataBase. Meu objetivo é estudo mesmo, estou realizando um trabalho

Comment: Entendi. Tenho dúvidas se é o caso de reabrir a pergunta ou não, tem várias maneiras de se fazer isso e "a melhor" depende da situação. De qualquer forma a resposta abaixo já te dá uma das alternativas (sessões). Sessões são para persistir dados dentro de uma mesma "rodada" (sessão) de uso, os casos de uso não são tantos. Geralmente faz mais sentido armazenar dados em um banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, cada execução de um programa PHP começa "pedra limpa", virgem. Para persistir dados ao longo de diversos acessos do mesmo cliente, é preciso criar uma sessão.

No início do programa, chame

```
session_start()
```

e substitua as referências à matriz "escolhas" por

```
$_SESSION['escolhas']
```

visto que apenas a matriz associativa $_SESSION é persistida entre sessões, o que você quer que dure, tem de ficar ali dentro.

Para iniciar a matriz na primeira vez (quando ela ainda não existe na sessão corrente) faça

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['escolhas']))
   $_SESSION['escolhas'] = array();
}
```

A propósito, vou descrever como funciona o mecanismo de sessão. Como eu disse antes, cada execução de uma página PHP começa do zero absoluto.

A função session_start() gera um código aleatório e insere esse código no cabeçalho da resposta HTTP, que no lado cliente (browse) é armazenada num cookie.

Quando o mesmo cliente acessa outra página do mesmo servidor, o cookie é enviado no cabeçalho da requisição HTTP. A função session_start() detecta esse cookie, e determina que o cliente já é conhecido.

O cookie armazena apenas um "session ID". O conteúdo da variável $_SESSION fica armazenada no servidor, geralmente numa pasta de arquivos temporários (/tmp no Linux).

O cliente não tem como acessar o conteúdo de $_SESSION diretamente, então é considerado seguro deixar informações sensíveis nele.

As informações de uma sessão devem ser consideradas voláteis. Se alguma coisa precisa persistir para além de uma sessão (por exemplo, se um cliente acessa a informação de mais de um computador diferente), aí é preciso guardá-la num banco de dados.

É possível armazenar a sessão em banco de dados, caso em que ela não se perde mesmo se o servidor for resetado ou substituído. Isto é útil, por exemplo, quando há um cluster de servidores respondendo por um mesmo site, e a sessão deva ser mantida mesmo que as requisições do cliente caiam em diferentes máquinas. Também é útil quando o site roda dentro de um container Docker, pois o restart do container já apagaria todas as sessões se elas fossem armazenadas na forma de arquivos temporários.

As sessões são um mecanismo ideal para quando o PHP serve páginas Web tradicionais. Para Webservices, pode-se considerar alguma outra tecnologia como JWT.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas realizei as mudanças ainda assim ele não acumula durante sessões. Codigo: http://dontpad.com/sessionphp

Comment: O problema é que você está inicializando $_SESSION['escolhas'] = array() uma segunda vez. Logo depois do include. Remova essa linha.

Comment: @epx Muito obrigado, agora entendi. É erro bem besta meu.